# WebAPI - запрос с query-параметрами

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Делаю API:
Конфиругация:

```
        var address = "http://localhost:50353";
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(address); //TODO: конфигурация

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetPackages",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{importStartDate}/{importEndDate}/{deliveryStartDate}/{deliveryEndDate}/{status}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Package",
                action = "GetPackages",
                importStartDate = RouteParameter.Optional,
                importEndDate = RouteParameter.Optional,
                deliveryStartDate = RouteParameter.Optional,
                deliveryEndDate = RouteParameter.Optional,
                status = RouteParameter.Optional,
            }

        );
```

Класс контроллера:

```
public partial class PackageController : ApiController
{
    [Route("package/{packageId}/{typeId}")]
    public List<TreeNode> GetPackageContentByType(int packageId, int typeId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Route("package/{importStartDate?}/{importEndDate?}/{deliveryStartDate?}/{deliveryEndDate?}/{status?}")]
    [ActionName("GetPackages")]
    public List<TreeNode> Get([FromUri]DateTime? importStartDate, [FromUri]DateTime? importEndDate, [FromUri]DateTime? deliveryStartDate, [FromUri]DateTime? deliveryEndDate, [FromUri]int? status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

По URL http://localhost:50353/package/1/1 захожу в метод, получаю честный NotImplementedException.
По URL http://localhost:50353/package?importStartDate=2018-04-05 получаю ошибку:

> No action was found on the controller 'Package' that matches the
>   request.

В метод, само собой, не попадаю.

Похоже, что-то не так в маршруте, но что - не могу понять.

Comment: А если `http://localhost:50353/package/2018-04-05` ?

Comment: @AGS17 вполне ожидаемо "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'packageId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'" и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте специфицировать типы у параметров роутинга:

```
public class PackageController : ApiController
{
    [Route("package/{packageId:int}/{typeId:int}")]
    public List<TreeNode> GetPackageContentByType(int packageId, int typeId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Route("package")]
    public List<TreeNode> Get(DateTime? importStartDate, DateTime? importEndDate, DateTime? deliveryStartDate, DateTime? deliveryEndDate, int? status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

И удалите маппинг `GetPackages` из конфига

Ожидаю, что должно работать по `http://localhost:50353/package?importStartDate=2018-04-05`

[Почитать](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: И какая это будет дата? Любая из них может быть null, поэтому мне и нужны query-параметры

Comment: @Zufir вы сами такой роутинг сделали. Исправил ответ.